# Can I approve the duplicate votes on my own question if I've edited it?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

When someone suggests that your post is a duplicate, you can see a button to approve that suggestion and instantly close your question. But if you make an edit after they suggest it, the button disappears:

> [image: no button]

Is there a way to approve the duplicate votes without waiting for more close votes in this situation?

Comment: Try voting to close it yourself, this will hopefully bring the button back.

Comment: I cast a recommend closure flag on your question in the screenshot, so the button should be there again now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the notice to reappear by voting to close your own question as a duplicate, or by casting a recommend closure flag if you have less than 250 reputation. Alternatively, you can simply wait for another close vote or close flag by someone else.

If you already voted or flagged to close your question before editing it, you can't get the notice to show again on your own question yourself: you have to wait for someone else's close vote or flag.

Voting (not flagging) to close your question before approving the votes has two other utilities: first, if you believe it to be a duplicate of a *different* target, you can vote to close it as a duplicate of that other target, and then approve the votes, so that both targets show once the question is closed; second, your name will be mentioned as one of the close voters in addition to the Community user.

Comment: Maybe there is direct (manually entered) link to force closing? I mean with the same action like “that’s solve my problem” button.

Comment: @alexolut I think that's a server-side action (akin to a button), and not a simple URL to access.

Comment: need one more question to inspect the page source code.

Comment: @Sonic good chance it's just a simple AJAX, so possible.